# XML export in excel doesn't respect cell format

Tags: xml, excel

I have an excel table where the cell format is set to numbers with 3 digits. when I export this table to an XML, the numbers I get in the XML file are with 14 digits while I need only 3. I precise that I check the box keep the format when I do the exporting. here is the XML I get:

```
  <years>
 <Y2013>33.62462779075865</Y2013> 
 <Y2014>34.29511617341695</Y2014> 
 <Y2015>22.99556015765178</Y2015> 
 <Y2016>21.72323650695616</Y2016> 
 <Y2017>23.47566955177833</Y2017> 
  </years>
```

in the original table I have : 33.625 , 34.295 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that worked for me is to build a quick vba function that returns String instead of a double. I used the following instructions:

```
value=Format(value, "0.000") 'returns a string formatted like 0,001 or 35,000
value= replace(value, ",",".") ' permits to set the right separator
```

value can be at the beginning in any type but becomes a String at the end